# I need to make my font responsive in a mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, responsive-design, media-queries

I have tried using media queries as below but it dint help even tried a % value for the font size. Please note outside the media queries I have a font size of 18pt for now and in mobile view I need font size of 10pt. Have tried possible ways I could google.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        user-access-panel .details-panel .panel-body {
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
            width: 100.29%;
            height: 130px;
            background-image: url("./images/icons/request-ID-card-bg.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            color: #3d4045;
            /*font-family:  Helv-neue-light;*/
            background-color: white;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 1px lightgray;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But what is the default font size? Before the media query?

Comment: This would be helpful [link](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: My default font size outside the media query is 18pt .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pt` is a unit used for printing - for screen you should use `px`, or even better `em` or `rem`.  Especially `rem` is useful for repsonsive design since 1 rem is the browser's default size, which usually is a proper size for "normal" text (i.e. in a paragraph, not in headers)

Comment: Hi as per your suggestion I changed 18 pt to 2.5 rem. But the font did not shrink in responsive mobile view.

Comment: 1.) The rule you posted only applies to this selector: `user-access-panel .details-panel .panel-body`. Try to set up more general rules, or rules whicht overwrite the specific rules in your regular CSS, using the same selectors. 2.) 2.5 rem is very big, that would be 40px  in most browsers

Comment: 1.5rem* my mistake. Yes I want the rule to be applied to that part only. How can I overwrite. I thought setting up a default value and then setting up a value for mobile view (using media queries) does overwrite the default setting. Can you specify what you mean by overwriting.

Comment: The media needs to be placed *after* the original rule to overwrite it (= replace it). If that still isn't enough, try to add `!important` after the size, like `font-size: 1.5rem !important;`

Comment: Wow.. That was my only mistake. I'll remember that to over-write we need to write it later . So media queries are not prioritized in CSS.Css tricks indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vw` units for font size to achieve this affect. But please review browser support for this option: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units.

```css
.responsive-type {font-size: 15vw;}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-type">
 <p>I am responsive</p>
</div>
```